# Is it possible to re-name crew-members in-game?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I know it's possible to re-name your starting crew at the hangar, but I can't seem to find any way to do this once I'm in-game. I prefer to give my crew custom names since it's easier for me to remember the jobs I've assigned each of them (i.e. pilot, shield operator, et cetera).

Is it possible to re-name crew-members outside of the hanger, and if so, how?

Comment: From all the let's plays I've seen, no, it's not possible.

Comment: Dude, that would be so convenient! To make do, I just have a standard order for assigning them, and just remember that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Added in v1.54, the Advanced Edition. [Changelog](http://www.ftlgame.com/FTLChangeLog.html):
>
> **Rename mid game**: Rename any crewmember from the Crew Manifest screen

According to the FTL website, the coming expansion, FTL: Advanced Edition, will allow renaming of crew mid-game. Coming in "early 2014". Keep your eyes peeled!

Answer (score 20):

With the free expansion "Advanced Edition" you're now able to rename any crew member from the crew manifest screen.

Comment: This answer was once correct, but is no longer correct as of the free expansion pack, FTL: Advanced Edition. Since it's free, there's no reason you shouldn't have it installed :)

Comment: Yep, updated it.